# Installing remote management profile in ipad

Tags: ios

I installed OS X server version 3.1.1 on mac mini... OSX in mac is 10.9.2

I am trying to use profile manager to remotely manage my ipad...

everything is configured according to the server manual..

DNS, open directory, server's host name are all set...

in ipad, i opened Sefari and went to   myserver.local/mydevices, I installed the profiles for "settings for everyone" and "Trust profile for (company name)" sucessfully,

then i clicked on "devices" to enroll the device...

then it brought me to settings to install the remote management profile... after i click install, it pops up a dialog saying "Profile Installation Failed. Profile failed to install"

please take a look at screen shot:

http://frankiegamescom.ipage.com/articles/profile_manager2.png 
http://frankiegamescom.ipage.com/articles/profile_manager.png

If you know how to fix, please help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please note that this question is offtopic for stackoverflow, since it is not about software development. Your question is better suited on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://ServerFault.com)